# How to get the focus on an inactive MainWindow?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I make a simple program using Qt. I use two main windows (`QMainWindow`) at the same time :

- Both main windows have push buttons;
- I set focus to both MainWindow1 and MainWindow2 (using `thread` and `sleep` for 4 seconds time intervals between clicking the push buttons);
- When MainWindow1 is active and MainWindow2 is inactive, only focus of the active window (MainWindow1) is running.

How can I get the focus of the inactive main window?